# How can I add rule to iptables on ubuntu to enable redis on local ip but not external

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall, linode, redis

I've followed the various scripts to set up 2 linode machines.
Both have an external and local Ip.
On one I have installed redis, and I want to connect to this machine via the local ip.

Which rules should I add specifically to allow access from my other linode to port 6379(redis), but not from the rest of the internet?

My /etc/iptables.firewall.rules so far:

```
----
*filter

#  Allow all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

#  Accept all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#  Allow all outbound traffic - you can modify this to only allow certain traffic
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

#  Allow HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere (the normal ports for websites and SSL).
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

#  Allow SSH connections
#
#  The -dport number should be the same port number you set in sshd_config
#
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

#  Allow ping
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

#  Log iptables denied calls
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7

#  Drop all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include this rule somewhere before the `-A INPUT -j DROP` rule:

```
-A INPUT -s 123.45.67.8 -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT
```

Change `123.45.67.8` to the IP address of the server you wish to permit access to.

Comment: Thank you! It's tricky to fiddle with these settings as one error might lock you out ;^)   I'll test it and accept the answer if it works

Comment: what if I need to add ip6tables for some ip address say 2802:306:c53e:8610:8839:dd55:45d8:45b4.

Comment: @anandaravindan, post a new question or search previous questions on how to configure ip6tables.